# Can anyone identify this tree?

Tags: trees

Can anyone help identify this tree? Found in Surrey, BC, Canada. Red Alder?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with you; I believe it is a red alder as well. Given the climate and trees common to the area, it seems most likely. The only other tree I know of that is orange in color up north is the osage orange, but that is much bushier than the tree you show.